# How to disable controls when checkbox is deselected or not selected at all in jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following html

```
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="[1]option" value="Hourly" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="[2]option" value="Daily">
    <input type="checkbox" name="[3]option" value="Weekly">
    <input type="checkbox" name="[4]option" value="Monthly">
    <input type="checkbox" name="[5]option" value="Yearly">
  </p>

   <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cheque" value="cheque" disabled>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Online" value="Online" disabled>
    <input type="text" name="Accountnumber" id="generate" disabled>
  </p>
</form>
```

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
         $('#generate').prop('disabled', false);
         $("input").prop('disabled', false);
     });
</script>
```

It works. But if I deselect all checkbox, the controls are not getting disabled.
My requirement is if only any check box is selected the controls should get enabled. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector along with `length` property. Also I would recommend the use of `change` event.

```
$("input:checkbox").on('change', function () {
    var status = $("input:checkbox:checked").length; // $("input:checkbox").is(":checked")
    $('#generate').prop('disabled', status);
});
```